# Send silent (data) notification to iOS device through FCM after swiping app from recent

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-notifications

I'm able to send data notifications, when is the app in foreground or background, but I no longer receive them after swiping app in the recent apps menu. Text notifications are always working.

So, something like this is always working:

```
{"to":"DEVICE_TOKEN","notification":{"title":"title test","body":"body test"},"priority":"high"}
```

But, in my case, I need silent (data) notifications. 
According to the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) I need high priority and content_available set to true:

```
{"to":"DEVICE_TOKEN","data":{"foo":"bar"},"priority":"high", "content_available":true}
```

But I'm not receiving any notification. Why is that and how can I fix that?

I'm aware of this note:

> Note that silent notifications in APNs are not guaranteed to be
>   delivered, and can depend on factors such as the user turning on Low
>   Power Mode, force quitting the app, etc.

but I have a full battery, charging and lower power mode is disabled.
The testing device is iPhone 6 running on iOS 11.2.6.

This question is not about differences between remote and silent notifications. I've made my research, but I couldn't find why it doesn't work. Whole setup looks fine to me, yet for some reason I'm not receiving silent notifications (but I do receive remote) after closing the app from recent apps list.

Comment: *but I no longer receive them after swiping app in the recent apps menu.* do you force quitting the app?

Comment: I swiped the app in recent apps menu. I still can receive text notifications, but no more silent notifications.

Comment: What does swipe mean? Do you mean force quit/ terminate the app?

Comment: I mean swipe app from here: https://img.gadgethacks.com/img/74/99/63569438614217/0/55-coolest-new-ios-9-features-you-didnt-know-about.w1456.jpg

Comment: Did you read the last 2-3 paragraphs from the other answer? What did you understand from that? Can you explain why it doesn't answer your question? Because whats happening for you **is the expected behavior of iOS**